# Extract string from the first position that's not "0" SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to find the first position of a value that's not "0" in a string so that I can extract the values that come after. The strings are all length 10. The strings all start with D and then a variable amount of "0" and I need to find the first position in the string that's not a "0". Examples:

```
String      Need to extract
D009902167, 9902167
D000128677, 128677
D000004395, 4395
```

I first wanted to do it like this:

```
Mid(Stringname,InStr(2,Stringname, <>"0"))
```

But I've now read that InStr doesn't accept <>, ! or NOT. How can I extract the string from the first position where the value isn't "0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`MID()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-function-427e6895-822c-44ee-b34a-564a28f2532c) to remove the 1st char and then add `0` to get only a numeric result (Access will do an implicit cast to integer):

```
SELECT MID(Stringname, 2) + 0
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need  the val of the string whitout left "D" 
for this you could replace() the D with empty string and get the val()

```
     val(Replace(Stringname, "D", "") )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy task in SQL, but my approach would be:

1. Strip out the zeroes
2. Locate the character you want to look for
3. Search for that character in the string that doesn't have the characters stripped out

All together, that would look like this:

```
Mid(
    Stringname,
    InStr(
        2,
        Stringname,
        Left(   
            Replace(
                Stringname,
                "0",
                ""
            ), 
            2
        )
    )
)
```

If your string just contains numbers, you can use `Format` to strip out leading zeroes without casting:

```
Format(Mid(StringName, 2))
```